# Core Data main context concurrency

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, core-data

So I've been reading about and working with Core Data pretty extensively over the past few weeks, and I've ended up implementing my Core Data stack using the following setup:

Save context - root context tied to the store, on PrivateQueue

Main context - running on main thread, child of save context

Edit contexts - created on-demand in any thread to edit UI data in the background as children of main context

With this setup, I haven't been having any issues, and I've taken the necessary precautions to prevent multiple background edit contexts from calling [editMoc save] simultaneously, but I'm not seeing how this is safe relative to the main thread/context. Specifically, all the code I keep seeing while using this setup is like the following:

```
[edit performBlock^{
      [edit save:nil];
      [main performBlock:^{
          [main save:nil];
          [root performBlock...]
      }];
}];
```

Now the thing I have not been able to figure out is this: every time the child context saves, the data is being propagated to the main context, but nothing is happening to ensure that the data isn't currently being read from/acted upon in the main context, right? Essentially, I feel like something like this would be more appropriate:

```
[edit performBlock^{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [edit save:nil];
      });
      [main performBlock:^{
          [main save:nil];
          [root performBlock....]
      }];
}];
```

At least if it were done that way, we'd ensure that the propagation is safe relative to the main thread/UI, no? This sort of ties in with my other question of "why should the main context *really* be associated with the main thread anyways?" Right now if I need to execute a fetch, I do it from the main context and I can understand that it then makes sense for it to be on the main thread, but if propagations can just happen "whenever" (since we **aren't** doing them on the main thread) what is the ultimate point of having it tied to the main thread? I don't even need to do a fetch because the data has seemingly unsafely arrived in the main context from the child save, yeah? From there a simple [tableView reload] suffices.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So I think I've found the answer to my question, which is that Core Data does in fact internally push the changes from the child context to the parent context using the correct thread (i.e. using the parent context's queue - which in this case would be the main queue). Meaning that it would in fact have to wait for anything else happening on the main thread that may have been using that data before it will dirty the main context.